# When upgrading a .NET Framework project to .NET 5, does it make sense to migrate business logic to .NET Standard 2.0 as a middle ground?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So currently, we have a large(ish) backend project, running on .NET Framework 4.7.2, that serves a web API. It has a lot of low quality code, and uses a lot of outdated dependencies.

We want to upgrade this API and make it easier to work on, including running on .NET 5, improving the code quality, upgrading dependencies etc.

So what we have started with is creating a new .NET Standard 2.0 project, and migrating code over class by class. As we migrate each class, we upgrade it to use dependency injection like it will be in .NET 5, fix code quality issues, add unit tests, and consolidate dependencies. We can incrementally test our code changes as we go, as after migrating each piece of code, we deploy and test the changes.

The idea is once we have migrated across all the business logic classes to .NET Standard, we can then delete the .NET Framework project and create a new .NET 5 project, that contains all the controllers, which then call the business logic in the Standard project.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach? Or should we be doing the upgrade in place?
Thanks

Comment: I believe this is opinion based question.  But upgrading the way you are doing it seems reasonable.  Just need to be careful if the codebase is large that you might need to fix a lot of things as net core does not support some classes from .NET Framework.

Comment: This IS an opinion-based question and I will be voting to close it as such.  That said, yes, this is typically an advisable approach if you want to piecemeal the upgrade. Otherwise you can simply take on the effort of upgrading everything at one place.  Without knowing the specifics of your codebase and your organization, it is impossible to say one way or the other.